# Counting occurrences of integer from random outcome

Tags: javascript, count

I'm fairly new to coding and have this practice that I can't figure out the last part of it.
I'm rolling three dice and supposed to count how many combined value of sevens I get at 1000th roll.
Do I have to create an array? the hint given to me was to create a counter variable. But I can't find any solution. I know it must be something simple. I need your guidance!

```js
var getRandomInt = function(x) {
    var result = 0;
    result = Math.floor((Math.random() * x) + 1);
    return result;
};

//variables I need
var diceOne = 0;
var diceTwo = 0;
var diceThree = 0;
var diceSum = 0;
var roll = 0;
var average = 0;


for (var i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {

    //Simulate a Dice Roll

    diceOne = getRandomInt(6);
    diceTwo = getRandomInt(6);
    diceThree = getRandomInt(6);
    roll = roll + 1;
    diceSum = diceOne + diceTwo + diceThree;
    average += diceSum / 1000;

    console.log("Roll #" + roll);
    console.log("Value of Dice 1 is " + diceOne);
    console.log("Value of Dice 2 is " + diceTwo);
    console.log("Value of Dice 3 is " + diceThree);
    console.log("The Sum of the Dice is " + diceSum);


    // Announce average and count of 7s

    if (i == 1000) {
        console.log("The Average is " + average);


    }

}
```

Comment: your code looks fine, except the last check for reaching the last loop. you could put the output after the loop. what is actually the question?

Comment: @NinaScholz the question is, How many times, out of the 1000 rolls, did the three dice have a combined value of seven?

Comment: @Incredible.J: just in case you might want to scale your problem to arbitrary dice quantity, rolls and expected result, you may check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59765343/11299053).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to count the times the 3 dice add up to 7, you can create a variable to keep track of this.

Inside your loop, you increase this by one everytime `diceSum` is 7.

```js
var getRandomInt = function(x) {
    var result = 0;
    result = Math.floor((Math.random() * x) + 1);
    return result;
};

//variables I need
var diceOne = 0;
var diceTwo = 0;
var diceThree = 0;
var diceSum = 0;
var roll = 0;
var average = 0;
var sevenCount = 0;


for (var i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {

    //Simulate a Dice Roll

    diceOne = getRandomInt(6);
    diceTwo = getRandomInt(6);
    diceThree = getRandomInt(6);
    roll = roll + 1;
    diceSum = diceOne + diceTwo + diceThree;
    average += diceSum / 1000;

    console.log("Roll #" + roll);

    console.log("The Sum of the Dice is " + diceSum);
    if(diceSum === 7){
      sevenCount = sevenCount + 1;
    }

    // Announce average and count of 7s

    if (i == 1000) {
        console.log("The Average is " + average);
        console.log("The seven count is " + sevenCount);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They're teaching you something that's actually really good to know.

You don't *have* to remember all values in order to calculate the average or number of 7s. You only have to count how many 7s you've seen and keep another variables that's the sum of all the values you've seen.

Edit: if you want to count the number of 7s you've seen, you need to create a variable, say `count_7s` and every time you see a 7, you increment `count_7s = count_7s + 1`.

Comment: the average was one of the questions asked. The next part is counting the 7s generated. I can't think of a way to count how many 7s I've seen. :(

Comment: @Incredible.J I've added some extra info. Try to think about it a bit more before asking on stack overflow. Think about how you would do it on a piece of paper. This is very simple and you're bound to attract negative attention :D.

Answer (score 0):

You need no roll count, because you loop the same amount, and you need a counter for sevens. An you could take a variable for `sum` and calculate later the average. This is better in terms of numerical precision.

At the end show the result of average and count of sevens.

```js
var getRandomInt = function(x) {
        return Math.floor((Math.random() * x) + 1);
    },
    sum = 0,
    average = 0,
    sevens = 0;

for (var i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
    let diceSum = getRandomInt(6) + getRandomInt(6) + getRandomInt(6);
    sevens += diceSum === 7;
    sum += diceSum;
}

average = sum / 1000;
console.log("The Average is " + average);
console.log("The Count of Sevens " + sevens);
```